# Unsolicited suggestions in comments - ok or not?

Tags: discussion, comments

Pure curiosity whether this is okay... Let's say I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15643641/elements-inside-the-div-are-not-center-aligin) which is about why certain CSS layout isn't working.  OP didn't ask for it or make any mention of what tools they're using, but I am tempted to suggest to them to try Firebug if they aren't already. (Because I am familiar with Firebug, and I know it's hugely helpful on web development, layouts, etc.)

Is this okay or I shouldn't put in unsolicited suggestions?

Comment: Providing you are trying to help the OP, I find unsolicited suggestions in comments perfectly fine and sometimes extremely useful. I browse the WPF tag mostly and often leave comments suggesting the OP use a 3rd party debugging tool that many users don't know about, or sometimes comment about bad practices I see in their code that are unrelated to their question but could lead to problems later on

Comment: Some posters do get annoyed at random suggestions, usually with the response like "Why are you telling me about x, I am asked about y", but in general, just ignore those as a majority of unsolicited suggestions are appreciated... and don't forget that suggestions (via comment or answer) are not just for the OP but for anyone else reading so even if the OP didn't find it helpful, someone else might.

Answer (score 8):

**That's perfectly fine.**

Comments are *intended* for helpful hints like good tools to use that don't rise all the way to the level of complete answers.